# Using ARGB for google circle is erroring

Tags: java, android

My error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method argb(FFFF)I in class 
Landroid/graphics/Color; or its super classes (declaration of 
'android.graphics.Color' appears in 
/system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
```

I am trying to use argb to give an alpha to my geo fence on a google map but I am getting this error on android api 25 and below.

```
 mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
     .center(new LatLng(personnelDataModel.getProjectGeoCoordinate().getLatitude(), personnelDataModel.getProjectGeoCoordinate().getLongitude()))
     .radius(personnelDataModel.getProjectSiteGeofenceRadiusInMetres())
     .fillColor(Color.argb(0.4f, 56, 119, 127))
     .strokeWidth(2)
 );
```

Comment: The [`Color.argb()` overload that takes `float`s](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb(float,%20float,%20float,%20float)) wasn't introduced until API level 26. Your RGB values are out of range for that anyway, btw.

Comment: Aside from this compiler error, the rgb values should be normalized into the 0..1 range as well as the a.

Comment: @MikeM. Should I swap it out for .fillColor(Color.argb(0.4f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f)) for example?

Comment: If you want one call to work on all versions, you'll need to use the overload that takes `int`s, so just multiply your alpha by 255; e.g., `int alpha = (int) 0.4f * 255;`.

Comment: Oops, that should've been `int alpha = (int) (0.4f * 255);`, otherwise you'll get zero for everything. Also, that was assuming you're using variable values for the color components, and your snippet was just an example. If you're using a static value, then what you have in your answer is perfectly fine. I'm not sure why those reviewers thought your answer wasn't an answer, but you should be able to undelete it yourself. If you can't, please let me know. If you do get it undeleted, also let me know, so I can comment there that it's a perfectly acceptable answer, so it doesn't get deleted again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have hex value of color you can use `Color.parseColor()` as `fillColor()` expects input to be integer.

```
String myPassedColor = "#aaaaaa"
Color.parseColor(myPassedColor)
```